# The type or namespace name 'WindowsAzure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I have this on top of my C# class:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

I have also made sure the nuget package is up to date.

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
The type or namespace name 'WindowsAzure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

None of the solutions in the previously asked questions worked

Comment: What assemblies is your project currently referencing? Is your NuGet console targeting the correct project in your solution?

Comment: @Dai Ok, I just noticed the actual .dll doesn't even exist in the path that the project displays for the WindowsAzure.Storage assembly. How would I fix this? I installed the package via NuGet

Comment: Nevermind, it does exist. Yes my console is targetting the correct project

Comment: I'm not sure why none of the literally hundreds of previous questions here about *The type or namespace name <someclass> does not exist in the namespace <someassembly>* can't help you troubleshoot this issue. While none of them may reference the specific namespace or assembly, the solutions to the problem are almost always the same. How many of those previous questions have you actually read to see if there was information that might help you solve it?

Comment: @KenWhite I have tried the suggested solutions on the previously asked questions. They did not work. That's why I asked the question

Comment: You tried *every single one* of the 1,796 results for a search of `The type or namespace does not exist` on this site? I highly doubt that's the case. There are only a few causes (and solutions) for this problem. I'm quite certain they're all covered in one of the *Related* posts to the right, or the other posts you can find here searching for the error message.

Comment: Why the hell would I be going through 1800 results to read the same few solutions over and over? I went through at least 20-25 of the similar questions and almost all the answers overlapped, and yes I tried them all. I wouldn't have asked the question otherwise.

Comment: If you feel your question not a duplicate include more details in the question itself proving it. For example please list the exact name of the NuGet package you are using (you told us you updated the package but never said which package you updated), also show a screenshot of your References expanded out showing that the DLL is actually added, please include the "Properties window" with the dll clicked so we can see its details, if you do that I will retract my duplicate vote.

Answer (score -2):

Check if the namespace exists in the Reference folder in your solution explorer. If it doesn't manually add it by right clicking on the folder and `Add reference`

Comment: Namespaces don't exist in the reference folder. Namespaces and assemblies are orthogonal concepts. What you see under references are (referenced) assemblies.

Comment: The referenced assembly does exist under references